# How to use the dot merge in keras 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am building a recommender system using deep learning. When defining my model I get the following error:

> ValueError: Layer dot_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [, ]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Code for class

```
    # The constructor for the class
    def __init__(self, n_users, m_items, k_factors, **kwargs):
        # U is the embedding layer that creates an User by latent factors matrix.
        # If the input is a user_id, U returns the latent factor vector for that user.
        U = Sequential()
        U.add(Embedding(n_users, k_factors, input_length=1))
        U.add(Reshape((k_factors,)))

        # M is the embedding layer that creates a Movie by latent factors matrix.
        # If the input is a movie_id, M returns the latent factor vector for that movie.
        M = Sequential()
        M.add(Embedding(m_items, k_factors, input_length=1))
        M.add(Reshape((k_factors,)))

        super(CFModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # The dot layer takes the dot product of user and movie latent factor vectors to return the corresponding rating.
        self.add(dot([U, M], axes=1))
```

The error is occurring when I am trying to perform the dot product on my two sequential models.

```
self.add(dot([U, M], axes=1))
```

In an earlier version of keras I was able to use the Merge layer mode = 'dot' to perform this operation. I assumed the newest version would work the same way.

Any one able to help me with this error?